# How can I keep a map pin in the same position on a map?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to keep the yellow marker in the same position on the on the map, even while scaling the map.

[image]

```css
.content-map {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 2.5%;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-map">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/icVEi.png" width="100%" />
  <div class="content-map-items">
    <img src="assets/img/fotoradar.png" width="30" height="40" class="fotoradar" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried to accomplish this. Where is your CSS that positions the marker?  You need to show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use relative positioning for the container (.content-map) and absolute positioning for the marker(.fotoradar) (and it's container (.content-map-items))

```css
.content-map {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 2.5%;
    padding-right: 2.5%;
}

.content-map .content-map-items {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.content-map .content-map-items .fotoradar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    transform:translate(-50%, -100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="content-map">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/W5Q4Uwe.png" width="100%" />
  <div class="content-map-items">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/klaMIKl.png" width="30" height="40" class="fotoradar" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The above would position the marker in the dead center of the map container. Then, to tweak the marker position, simply adjust the top and left percentages of the .content-map .content-map-items .fotoradar CSS rule.

Comment: While this may answer the question, please post a working example, not just the CSS. You should show that your answer actually works.

Comment: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6mo32gw1/1/

Comment: Do not add a fiddle, add the code to the question itself using the stack snippet tool. If that fiddle link becomes invalid, future users won't have an answer.

Comment: Okay, changed my JSFiddle into a stack snippet. Thanks for the tip @disinfor.